# Modules in MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module

I understand how MVC works with models, repositories and services in PHP.

Could anyone explain to me what is the role of Modules and are they related to MVC in any way?

I would even appreciate any links relating to this topic. Cannot find anything interesting myself

Comment: "Module" means nothing. You should as well call it "Component" or "Section". As for *with what** MVC works .. well ... there are no multiple "models". Only single model layer (which, among other things, contains those services and repositories).

Answer (score 1):

Module definition:

> each of a set of standardized parts or independent units that can be
>   used to construct a more complex structure, such as an item of
>   furniture or a building.

A module is typically a portion of code that provides a specific functionality in a project or framework.

You could think of a plugin in Wordpress as a module.

MVC itself stands for

- M - Model
- V - View
- C - Controller

As far as I am concerned modules don't really have anything to do with the MVC structure/design pattern... although they are a good way of creating self-contained bits of functionality that can be used across projects, just like plugins and Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Seems like I finally understand it :D